# No se visualizan mis imágenes al subirlas al hosting

Tags: laravel

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con laravel, en el que implementé la subida de archivos, como imágenes y pdf, ejecutándolo de manera local, los archivos se visualizan sin problema. Pero al subir el proyecto al servidor no los encuentra, me di cuenta que los archivos ya no se están guardando en la misma carpeta. La ruta que tenía asignada era esta:

```
<img src="{{asset('storage').'/'.$tecnico->fotoPerfil}}" alt="" width="200">
```

porque los archivos se guardaban así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cambié la ruta por esta:

```
<img src="{{asset('storage/app/public').'/'.$tecnico->fotoPerfil}}" alt="" width="200">
```

ya que los archivos se están guardando así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero el servidor sigue sin encontrarlos, no se si estoy poniendo bien la ruta,o si me estoy pasando algun punto, agradecería si alguien sabe como puedo resolverlo

Comment: Noto dos cosas: 1. No cambias nada en la ruta (o estoy leyendo mal) 2. El directorio public aparece dos veces en la segunda imagen (y al parecer el  public que aloja las imágenes no tiene que ver con el directorio público del host). Edita la pregunta, como está resulta difícil ofrecer algo que te ayude.

Comment: En laravel se usa crear un link simbólico `storage` en el directorio `/public` que apunta al directorio `/storage/app/public` con el comando `php artisan storage: link`. Posiblemente lo hayas creado en local, pero no en el hosting.

Comment: Edite la ruta, no me habia fijado que puse la misma en la parte de abajo. Es la que he estado implementado pero no me funciona ('storage/app/public') porque es donde ahora se están guardando los archivos.

Comment: Implementando el link simbólico en mi servidor, se podrían mostrar los archivos que se encuentren en la carpeta prinicipal storage/app/public/uploads? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias por sus sugerencias, lo logré implementando el enlace simbólico en la terminal de mi servidor con las rutas que correspondían

En el servidor me ubiqué en el lugar donde estaban almacenando mis imágenes, al estar ahí escribi pwd, para obtener la ruta completa
eso sería el "source" y después me dirigí a la carpeta public_html, y dentro de ella tenía que crear una carpeta llamada storage, asimismo escribi pwd para obtener la ruta completa que llamaríamos "destiny"

y ejecuté el comando dentro de public_html/storage

```
ln -s "source" "destiny"
```

así:

```
ln –s /home/123445/domains/sudominio.com/laravel/storage/app/public/uploads /home/12345/domains/sudominio.com/public_html /storage/uploads
```

gracias al compañero Carlos Hidalgo :)

Comment: Sería muy útil para los que vengan con tu misma duda, el que incluyas un fragmento de código o algo que indique cómo cambiaste lo que tenías hecho.

Comment: claro, lo haré :)

Answer (score 0):

imagino que no creaste el enlace con "php artisan storage:link", [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí][1] hay tenes la web oficial,igual al menos yo personalmente prefiero crear una ruta y un controlador que devuelva las imágenes por un motivo de seguridad(no mostrar la estructura y dar permisos de mas) y flexibilizad(poder modificar el retorno como nombre, fechas, formatos y demás, y claro que sirva de interfaz para poder alojar las imágenes en varios servidores o servicios de almacenamientos).
Otra cosa por la imagen una pequeña observación seria que agrupes las imagines por fecha o algo así, ya sabes por limitaciones de algunos servidores con formatos.
Perdón si soy algo metido.